# HTTP 400 status not hitting route events hook

Tags: ember.js

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandalsoft/eU8ua/

My app makes an ajax call to instagram to get a users' instagram feed, and redirects to authenticate when the user doesn't have a session.  Instagram returns a HTTP 400 when the `access_token` isn't valid, and I want to redirect based on that 400 status code.  But when the 400 response is returned from $.ajax(), it's not handled by the `events:` hook in the route.  I had code in the `setupController()` method to handle it, but that felt wrong.

Is `events:` the correct place to handle these HTTP codes and place redirect/transition logic?  If so, any ideas why it's not working? If not, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("instagram");
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    redirect: function() {
      this.transitionTo('instagram');
    }
});

App.InstagramRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        error: function(reason, transition) {
            console.log('err.  reason.status: ' + reason.status);
            if (reason.status === 400) {
                console.log('in evetns hook.  Unauthorized, redirecting to: ' + App.Instagram.authURL);
                this.transitionTo(App.Instagram.authURL);
            } else {
                console.log('err.  reason.status: ' + reason.status);
            }
        }
    },
    setupController: function(controller) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=NO_TOKEN",
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'JSONP',
            }).then(function(json){
                if (json.meta.code ===400) {
                    console.log('in setupController ERROR 400: json: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
                }
                else {
                    controller.set('model', json.data);
                }   
        });
    }
});

App.Instagram = Em.Object.extend({

});

App.Instagram.reopenClass ({

    authURL: 'https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' + App.Instagram.clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + App.Instagram.redirectUri + '&response_type=token',
    token: localStorage.Instagram_token,
    tokenChanged: function() {
       localStorage.token = this.get('Instagram_token');
     }.observes('token')
});
```

**UPDATE**:  The instagram web server is returning a HTTP 200, but the response JSON error code is 400.  So I can see that the `events:` hook might not trigger on that, but is it still proper to handle all 4xx application error codes in my setupController() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
App.InstagramRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
      error: function(reason, transition) {
          console.log('err.  code: ' + reason.code);
          if (reason.code === 400) {
              console.log('in evetns hook.  Unauthorized, redirecting to: ' + App.Instagram.authURL);
              this.transitionTo(App.Instagram.authURL);
          } else {
              console.log('err.  reason.code: ' + reason.code);
          }
      }
  },
  model: function(params, transition) {
      var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          $.ajax({
            url:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=NO_TOKEN",
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'JSONP',
            }).then(function(json){
                if (json.meta.code ===400) {
                    console.log('ERROR 400: json: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
                    reject(json.meta);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(json.data);
                }   
        });
      })
      return promise;
  }
});
```

I don't know if that code works, but it can give you a hint.

Comment: BINGO!  You saw what I was going for and got me where I wanted to go.  I struggled for 2 days trying to get the model: hook to work with a promise and couldn't, so I settled for setupController() which I thought might break the events: hook.  Good to know my intuition was right, but your code is *exactly* what I was trying to accomplish.  I'll dig into RSVP to figure out why this works, but this is awesome, thank you.

Comment: `events` is deprecated in Ember 1.0. Instead of `events` use `actions`.